# Помогите переделать код

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
.clearfix:after {visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }

* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;  }

.innerWrapper {
 max-width: 920px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

h2, h4 {
 font-family: 'Abril Fatface', serif;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 100px;
 margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

/* NAV SECTION */

.companyName {
 padding: 18px 17px 18px 15%;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 color: #fff;
 width: 45%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 text-align: left;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

nav {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 55%;
 float: right;
}


header nav ul {
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 border-right: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

header nav ul li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 display: inline;
 width: 25%;
 text-align: center;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

header nav ul li:hover {
 background: none;
  font-style: bold;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

header nav ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 25px 20px;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1rem;
}

header nav ul li a:focus {
 outline: none;
}

/* HEAD SECTION */

header {
 background: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/uploads/141319062591093cefc09/ad50c1f0?q=75&fm=jpg&s=a356dd61ff3da2269124bcd12a303b7e);
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

.hero {
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 1px 0 2px #595859;
}

.hero h1 {
 font-size: 5.5rem;
 margin:0;
 padding-top: 200px;
 font-family: 'Abril Fatface', serif;
 color: #fff;
}

.hero h3 {
 padding-bottom: 250px;
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin: 0;
}


@media (max-width:900px) {
  .companyName {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4% 4%;
  }
  
 .mainNav {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  header nav ul {
    border: none;
  }
  
  header nav ul li a {
    padding: 25px 2%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="navWrapper" id="home">
     <div class=" clearfix">
      <h2 class="companyName">Company Name</h2>
      <nav class="mainNav clearfix">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work" class="smoothScroll">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
     </div><!-- end .innerWrapper -->
    </div><!-- end of .navWrapper -->

    <section class="hero">
     <div class="innerWrapper">
      <h1>May I Have Your Attention, Please!</h1>
      <h3>I'm a tagline, What's up? </h3>
     </div><!-- end .innerWrapper (.hero) -->
    </section>
   </header>
```

Подскажите как убрать отступы от краев

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю ваша проблема решиться прописав для `body {margin: 0; padding: 0}`

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял Вас,

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    }
```